# Loop through mongoDB database arry using @foreach in express

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

Hi I have a database which I can access in a view using

html and express layout  I think @each and {{}} is a js syntax

```
{{posts[0].detail}}   <----------------This works
```

But I want to display all the contents of the post using

```
@each(post in posts)

{{post[don't know what to put here].detail}}

@end
```

Comment: What language is that syntax `@each(post in posts)`. Also, you probably have to either to `{{post.detail}}` or `{{posts[post].detail}}`

Comment: Well im using express as the layout and html for the view thats all I know I'm going to try posts[post].detail

Comment: {{posts[post].detail}} <--- did not work

Comment: What about `{{post.detail}}` ? What is the error that you get? Also, I don't see EJS having the `@each` syntax, are you sure you are using EJS for templating?

Comment: @Cristy woooooooooooooooooooooooooooo that worked thanksssssssssss

Answer (score 0):

What about {{post.detail}} from @Cristy

So this answered my question.

I thought @each(post in posts)  <----- you had to use posts.detail

Now I know post takes the attribute of posts.

Ex:

@each(post in cars) <------ would still be post.detail as well.